# Continuous function and definite integration $\int_{1/2}^{2} \sin\left(x-\frac1x\right) \frac1x\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$I=\int_{1/2}^{2} \sin\left(x-\dfrac1x\right) \dfrac1x\ dx$$

I tried going with integeration by parts but it's getting too much big and the powers are increasing. Can somebody help here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u = 1/x$, so that $du = -1/x^2 = -u^2 \, dx$. Then (note that the bounds remain unchanged)
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{1/2}^2 \sin\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x}\,dx
= \int_{1/2}^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{u}-u\right)u \cdot \frac{1}{u^2} \, du
= -\int_{1/2}^2 \sin\left(u-\frac{1}{u}\right) \frac{1}{u}\, du = -I,
\end{align}
since $x\mapsto\sin x$ is odd.
Hence $I = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $u=\dfrac1x$ then
$$I=\int_{1/2}^{2} \sin\left(x-\dfrac1x\right) \dfrac1x\ dx=-I$$